# 2x2 design for ANOVA

Tags: anova, experiment-design, sas

I am beginner with statistics and I need some help for my data analysis. 
In my research I am trying to find an impact of colors on websites and types
of webstores on customer trust, purchasing intention, preference etc.
For example websites selling insurance service will be
trusted more if the color of websites is blue than red.

Design of my research is 2x2 /color: red vs. blue $\times$ type of website: service vs. outlet.
I am not sure if I should use one-way anova or two-way anova and how the model
should look like. Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Do you have a single website that you are changing/manipulating yourself or are you testing a collection of real websites? Will each customer/participant see all website variants or only one?

Comment: I ran my experiment as a survey with imagined pictures of websites, but I made them according to real websites. I only made same changes as more visible background color... One group of respondents has showned only with blue version of websites /picture of website/ where was at first blue version of service store and later outlet webstore. The second group had survey only with red pictures of websites - again service webstore and outlet webstore.

Comment: Sounds like two different experiments to me, each comparing service and outlet using a single color.  But, it sounds like you haven't taken into account the potential effect of order of observation in your design.  If each respondent sees the service site first and the outlet site second, then the effect of order (first observed, second observed) is confounded with the effect of website type (service, outlet).